# query database with knockout.js / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, knockout.js

I'm following a knockout.js tutorial for loading data from the server and I'm a bit confused on where the query is actually coming from. The tutorial can be found [here](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving) and the specific bit of code I'm talking about is on page 2.

I understand the necessity for using ajax, but I'm not actually sure how to make a query based on what they're doing.

```
$.getJSON("query/tasks", function(allData) {
    var mappedTasks = $.map(allData, function(item) { return new Task(item) });
    self.tasks(mappedTasks);
});
```

The description of what is taking place:

```
On this server, there's some code that handles requests to the URL /tasks, and 
responds with JSON data. Add code to the end of TaskListViewModel to request that
data and use it to populate the tasks array:
```

So, say I'm working with PHP and want to make the following query to find the tasks:

```
$tasks= mysql_query("select * from tasks");
```

**Where would I place this query?** I see it's somehow related to /tasks, but what's going on here exactly?

**edit, would I do something like this?** So essentially the $.getJSON request is calling a function residing at query/tasks in this case?

```
//assuming this is on query.php

Class query{

    function tasks(){
        $task = mysql_query("select * from tasks");
        return $task;
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Essentially what is happening is that you are making an AJAX call to some endpoint on your server that will return JSON data.  I haven't worked with PHP in quite a while, but you are basically requesting a resource on your server.  Let's say that your website is http://www.myawesomesite.com.  If you were to make an AJAX request to "/tasks", there will be a request to http://www.myawesomesite.com/tasks that is expected to return JSON data.

That resource can be another page, a web-service of some kind, whatever you have available.  I work primarily in the ASP.NET MVC space, so my experience is different from PHP, but the idea is the same.  You are making a request to a resource on your server to return JSON data.  Whatever that resource is is up to you.  HTH!

Comment: I've used cakphp so I'm assuming it works in a similar way to how depending on the controller and the action, certain data will be sent to the view. So query/tasks would represent a method called tasks inside the query class(or rather just in query.php). Inside that tasks method I'd simply place the query and return the result? If this makes sense to anyone, care to comment? I also updated my code above....so essentially the $.getJSON request is calling a function residing at /tasks?